# Android SQLite multiple table input

Tags: android, sqlite, multiple-tables

I have a budget program that uses multiple tables to store information. When I try to add information to more than 1 table at a time, I end up only having the first table receive any information. This is the code I use:

```
public SQLiteDatabase createBudget(String bname, String bpay, String bamount,
                String bmemo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues t1 = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues t2 = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues t4 = new ContentValues();
            t1.put(KEY_NAME, bname);
            t1.put(KEY_PAYDAY,bpay);
            t2.put(KEY_AMOUNT, bamount);
            t4.put(KEY_MEMO, bmemo);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, t1);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, t2);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE4, null, t4);
            return ourDatabase;
        }
```

I'm completely lost on what to do. I have tried looking online but the things I have found are for single table database. I would appreciate any help. This is LogCat content:

```
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662): Error inserting budget_amount=99
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: Budget_Items.edit_date may not be NULL (code 19)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at budget.app.BudgetDB.createBudget(BudgetDB.java:161)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at budget.app.AddBudget$1.onClick(AddBudget.java:40)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 10:14:33.935: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662): Error inserting _memo=for pie
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: Budget_Memos.edit_date may not be NULL (code 19)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at budget.app.BudgetDB.createBudget(BudgetDB.java:162)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at budget.app.AddBudget$1.onClick(AddBudget.java:40)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 10:14:33.955: E/SQLiteDatabase(662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is "Budget_Items.edit_date may not be NULL". You have a NOT NULL column in your database and try to insert a row without giving a value at the column Budget_Items.edit_date

Comment: thank you for the help that was the issue i put a variable there and it runs fine now thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your constrain exception is very much visible here

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: Budget_Items.edit_date may not be NULL (code 19)

Try putting a try catch block around your calls to find the exact error.